# Making a stylesheet override all other stylesheets in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, overriding

I'm trying to figure out how to correctly define a stylesheet (say...bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss) to override all other stylesheets in my Ruby on Rails app. The thing is I want to leave all {wrap}bootstrap theme files I'm using intact so I can upgrade when updates come out. So all changes I may need to make should be done on this "overriding" css file.

Maybe something in application.css.scss?

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/
```

I've tried declaring this specific stylesheet after require_tree but nothing. I'm sure there are some concepts I'm not fully grasping. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about using Rails specifically, but the definitions in the last stylesheet (added to the page last) will trump preceding styles.

You need to ensure that the override stylesheet contains equivalent css selectors to ensure the styles will be overridden.